# My custom PHP framework's routing system isn't effectively preventing direct access to files within the 'views/' directory

Tags: php

I'm developing a custom PHP framework to simplify my daily work, especially for smaller web projects where I feel using Laravel is a bit heavy-handed. My router class is functioning well, but I've encountered an issue. Files within the 'views', 'classes', 'models', and 'controllers' folders are directly accessible. How can I prevent this direct access? Additionally, I've noticed that the '.htaccess' file is viewable via the URL "https://localhost:8000/.htaccess". Any ideas on how to address these concerns?

**classes/SimpleRouter.php**

```
<?php

namespace router;

class SimpleRouter
{
    private $routes = [];

    public function addRoute($method, $url, $handler)
    {
        // Convert the method to uppercase to standardize
        $method = strtoupper($method);

        // Check if the method is supported
        if (!in_array($method, ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])) {
            throw new \Exception("Unsupported method: $method");
        }

        $this->routes[$method][$url] = $handler;
    }

    public function route($method, $url)
    {
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $urlParts = $url ? explode('/', $url) : [];
        $handled = false;

        if (isset($this->routes[$method][$url])) {
            // Exact match found for the method and URL, call the handler
            $handler = $this->routes[$method][$url];
            $this->callHandler($handler);
            $handled = true;
        } elseif ($method !== 'GET') {
            // If the method is not GET and route not found, attempt matching with parameters
            $handled = $this->matchWithParams($method, $url, $urlParts);
        }

        if (!$handled) {
            // No matching route found or method not supported, invoke the default 404 handler
            $this->defaultRoute();
        }
    }

    private function callHandler($handler, $data = null)
    {
        if (is_callable($handler)) {
            // Callable function, invoke directly
            $handler();
        } elseif (is_string($handler) && strpos($handler, '@') !== false) {
            // Handler is in "Controller@method" format
            list($controllerName, $methodName) = explode('@', $handler, 2);
            $controller = "\\controllers\\$controllerName";

            if (class_exists($controller)) {
                $instance = new $controller();

                if (method_exists($instance, $methodName)) {
                    // Call the controller method and pass data if available
                    if ($data !== null) {
                        $instance->$methodName($data);
                    } else {
                        $instance->$methodName();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }

            // If the controller/method doesn't exist, invoke the default 404 handler
            $this->defaultRoute();
        } elseif (is_string($handler) && file_exists(__DIR__ . "/../views/{$handler}.php")) {
            // Handler is a view file, include it
            include_once __DIR__ . "/../views/{$handler}.php";
        } else {
            // Invalid handler or file not found, invoke the default 404 handler
            $this->defaultRoute();
        }
    }



    private function matchWithParams($method, $url, $urlParts)
    {
        foreach ($this->routes[$method] as $route => $handler) {
            $route = rtrim($route, '/');
            $routeParts = explode('/', $route);

            if (count($routeParts) === count($urlParts)) {
                $params = [];

                foreach ($routeParts as $key => $part) {
                    if (!empty($part) && $part[0] === '{' && $part[strlen($part) - 1] === '}') {
                        // Extract parameter name and pattern from {param:pattern}
                        preg_match('/{([^:]+)(:([^}]+))?}/', $part, $matches);

                        $paramName = $matches[1];
                        $pattern = isset($matches[3]) ? $matches[3] : null;

                        if ($pattern && !preg_match("/^$pattern$/", $urlParts[$key])) {
                            // Parameter value doesn't match the pattern, break and try the next route
                            break 2;
                        }

                        $params[$paramName] = $urlParts[$key];
                    } elseif ($part !== $urlParts[$key]) {
                        // If parts don't match, break and try the next route
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (count($params) > 0) {
                    // Match found, call the handler with parameters
                    $this->callHandlerWithParams($handler, $params);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // No match found for the given URL and parameters
        return false;
    }

    private function callHandlerWithParams($handler, $params)
    {
        if (is_callable($handler)) {
            // Callable function, invoke directly with parameters
            $handler($params);
        } elseif (is_string($handler) && strpos($handler, '@') !== false) {
            // Handler is in "Controller@method" format
            list($controller, $method) = explode('@', $handler, 2);
            if (class_exists($controller) && method_exists($controller, $method)) {
                // Controller and method exist, create instance and invoke method with parameters
                $instance = new $controller();
                $instance->$method($params);
            } else {
                // Controller or method not found, invoke the default 404 handler
                $this->defaultRoute();
            }
        } elseif (is_string($handler) && file_exists("views/{$handler}.php")) {
            // Handler is a view file, include it
            include_once "views/{$handler}.php";
        } else {
            // Invalid handler, invoke the default 404 handler
            $this->defaultRoute();
        }
    }

    private function defaultRoute()
    {
        include('views/errors/404.php');
    }
}
```

***Please Help. Thanks in advance!***

Comment: In a _default_ Apache configuration, requests for any files starting with `.ht` will be denied. So either someone explicitly changed that on your server, or you are using - something else (litespeed)?

Comment: it's on localhost and I do have a shared litespeed server.

in my .htaccess I have this:

`<Files ~ "^\.htaccess">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>`

Comment: Not sure if the `Satisfy All` is needed, but other than that, I don't see why that should not be working. (Not an expert on litespeed though myself.)

Comment: I too and as per router logic I am not sure how to block the direct access as well.

Comment: If you use Litespeed, then it's a Litespeed question and not PHP. You should fix your tags.